# Romance Wattpad book involving an ordinary girl, a floating island in the sky occupied by dragons, and a dragon shifter male lead

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

I read a Wattpad book a couple years ago and want to reread it but I can't remember the name.

The story is about girl who's quite ordinary but their world becomes disturbed by a floating island in the sky occupied by dragons. I remember that she has this reoccurring dream where she meets a man ( he is the male lead ) but he's a bit blurry in her memory.

Then she was selected for an event, like a hunt, that is going to be held in the floating island. It is rumored that all the girls who were selected weren't able to come back again, but in actuality, the event was like a mating event ceremony(?), something like that, and they get together with their mate/fated person ( turns out she's actually the mate of male lead that's why they are magically connected in the dream, yada yada).

I also vaguely recall that the male lead is the head knight(?) of the king of dragons and the best friend of our protagonist, who was also selected for the event and was also the mate of the dragon king.